# Converting mp4 to mp3

Tags: ffmpeg, lame

I have a video I need to convert to mp3 (from the command line - not GUI): `video.mp4`

I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i -b 192 video.mp4 video.mp3
```

with no success. I get the following error:

```
WARNING: library configuration mismatch
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 59.83 (29917/500) -> 59.75 (239/4)
WARNING: The bitrate parameter is set too low. It takes bits/s as argument, not kbits/s 
Encoder (codec id 86017) not found for output stream #0.0
```

so I tried lame:

```
lame -h -b 192 video.mp4 video.mp3
```

I get:

```
Warning: unsupported audio format
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: change -b to -ab

Answer (score 149, accepted):

For FFmpeg with Constant Bitrate Encoding (CBR):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn \
       -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 \
        audio.mp3
```

or if you want to use Variable Bitrate Encoding (VBR):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn \
       -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -qscale:a 4 -ar 48000 \
        audio.mp3
```

The VBR example has a target bitrate of 165 Kbit/s with a bitrate range of 140...185.

Comment: Assuming that lame is already installed.

Comment: ha thanks, that is exactly what i am looking for

Comment: The only extra step to this is `sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53`

Comment: Or since this is Ubuntu, [ubuntu-restricted-extras](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats), which includes libavcodec-extra-53 among other things.  You may have installed this already as the installation CD prompts to do so.

Comment: My edit added in a VBR example and labelled the fixed bitrate example as CBR...

Comment: For Ubuntu 14 users: http://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04 => use avconv instead

Comment: What is the difference between CBR and VBR? `When it comes to selecting VBR vs. CBR, It is almost always recommended that you use VBR encoding for your media files as it provides higher quality files. We would suggest that you do not use CBR unless you have a specific need for playback on a device that only supports CBR.`

Comment: Maybe you can leave `ar`, which should be in `Hz` and also leave `-qscale:a`

Answer (score 14):

[soundconverter](http://packages.ubuntu.com/soundconverter) [image: Install soundconverter]

[image: Install via the software center]

is the leading audio file converter for the GNOME Desktop. It reads anything GStreamer can read (Ogg Vorbis, AAC, MP3, FLAC, WAV, AVI, MPEG, MOV, M4A, AC3, DTS, ALAC, MPC, Shorten, APE, SID, MOD, XM, S3M, etc...), and writes to WAV, FLAC, MP3, AAC, and Ogg Vorbis files, or use a GNOME Audio Profile.

SoundConverter aims to be simple to use, and very fast. Thanks to its multithreaded design, it will use as many cores as possible to speed up the conversion. It can also extract the audio from videos.

**How to Convert MP4 to MP3 with VLC**

- Open VLC Media Player. Click "Media" > "Convert" to enter the "Open Media" window. Click the "Add" button on the right side of the screen to enter Windows Explorer. Locate the MP4 on your hard drive you want to convert. Click the "Convert" button at the bottom of the screen.
- Select the name of the Target file.
- Click the "Audio Codec" tab and select "MP3" from the "Codec" drop down box. Press the "Start" button to begin converting your MP4 to MP3 audio.
- Click Start

Comment: But the OP asked for a command-line solution.

Comment: This is great !!!

Answer (score 12):

I have a shell-script that uses `mplayer` (so it can convert anything `mplayer` can play) to extract the audio, and then encode it using `lame`.
Here is the code:

```
#! /bin/bash
# any2mp3.sh
# Converts to mp3 anything mplayer can play
# Needs mplayer amd lame installed

[ $1 ] || { echo "Usage: $0 file1.wma file2.wma"; exit 1; }

for i in "$@"
do
    [ -f "$i" ] || { echo "File $i not found!"; exit 1; }
done

[ -f audiodump.wav ] && {
    echo "file audiodump.wav already exists"
    exit 1
}

for i in "$@"
do
    ext=`echo $i | sed 's/[^.]*\.\([a-zA-Z0-9]\+\)/\1/g'`
    j=`basename "$i" ".$ext"`
    j="$j.mp3"
    echo
    echo -n "Extracting audiodump.wav from $i... "
    mplayer -vo null -vc null -af resample=44100 -ao pcm:waveheader:fast \
    "$i" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null || {
        echo "Problem extracting file $i"
        exit 1
    }
    echo "done!"
    echo -n "Encoding to mp3... "
    lame -m s audiodump.wav -o "$j" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
    echo "done!"
    echo "File written: $j"
done
# delete temporary dump file
rm -f audiodump.wav
```

First you need to `apt-get install mplayer lame`.
After that, put the code in a file named ''any2mp3.sh'', give permission to execute, and put that in your $PATH, and you will be able to do:

```
$ any2mp3.sh file.mp4 another-file.wma yet-another.file.ogg
```

It will convert each file passed to an mp3 with the same name.

It's a little rough, but does the job.

Comment: i did everything and i get: `-rw-r--r-- 1 aki aki     7104 2011-12-02 10:41 video.mp3` which does not play

Comment: that's weird... it seems that lame couldn't convert the wav. try removing the `>/dev/null 2>/dev/null` from the code to see the error message.

Comment: no luck, here's the output: http://pastebin.com/ALrTqCmk of both conversions

Comment: And does the audiodump.wav plays? If it doesn't, `mplayer` couldn't play the video.mp4 file, and then you're really out of luck. Maybe the file you are trying to convert is corrupted, can you test the process with another file?

Comment: no, the wav does not play, nor the mp4 from mplayer

Comment: Yeah, if `mplayer` can't play the mp4, then the conversion won't work with this method. :/

Comment: ah! you're welcome, glad you solved it! :)

Answer (score 9):

I think the problem is with your syntax of the ffmpeg command.

```
ffmpeg -i source_filename -vn -ab 192k -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 output_filename
```

should work.

Comment: i get: Expected number for ac but found: liblamemp3

Answer (score 9):

I use this small script for converting m4a to mp3.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.m4a; do
    avconv -i "$i" -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 "`basename "$i" .m4a`.mp3"
done
```

Comment: If it says `avconv` if not found install `ffmpeg ` and replace it with `ffmpeg`

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to understand a few things.

`MP3` is an *audio* format.

`MP4` is a *video* format.

To get the audio out of the MP4 (and to save it as an MP3), use [soundconverter](http://packages.ubuntu.com/soundconverter) [image: Install soundconverter].

Comment: +1 well done for pointing out the difference between mp4 and mp3.

Answer (score 3):

### To convert **Upd_Sanity.mp4** to **Upd_Sanity.mp3**

```
$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg && sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53

$ ffmpeg -i Upd_Sanity.mp4 -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 Upd_Sanity.mp3
```

**OR (as `ffmpeg` is deprecated)**

```
$ avconv -i Upd_Sanity.mp4 -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 Upd_Sanity.mp3
```

### Description

```
   -i        input file name
   -vn       disable video recording
   -acodec   force audio codec to libmp3lame
   -ac       set the number of audio channels
   -ar       set the audio sampling frequency
```

---

### If you need to use it frequently,

**STEP 1 : Create a bash function that performs conversion**

```
## utilities.sh
convertMP4toMP3(){
echo -n "Enter source mp4 file : "
read sourceFile

echo -n "Enter destination mp3 file : "
read destFile

avconv -i $sourceFile -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -ab 160k -ar 48000 $destFile
}
```

**STEP 2 : source that bash file**

```
 $ source utilities.sh
```

**STEP 3 : start conversion calling above function `convertMP4toMP3`**

```
 $ convertMP4toMP3
 Enter source mp4 file : Upd_Sanity.mp4
 Enter destination mp3 file : UPd_sanity.mp3
```

### References

[utilities.sh](https://github.com/iPrayag/dotfiles/blob/master/utilities.sh)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use Lame directly if you use FFmpeg and pipe the output to lame (via stdout and stdin). An example:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn -f wav - | \
       lame -V 3 - audio.mp3
```

This allows you to use lame's *considerable* commandline options if you wish to explore them...

Answer (score 0):

you can try converting it by vlc or sound converter
go to http://soundconverter.org/ sound converter or find in your software center
or use vlc for conversion
open vlc
media
convert/save
chose your file
chose output format
chose name and destination 
and start steaming
thats all

Answer (score 0):

Try Transmageddon is available trough the Ubuntu Software Center http://www.linuxrising.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Though it is GUI, you can use Audacity to control fixed or variable, as well as output quality, when doing MP4 to MP3 conversions.

Open Audacity, open the target MP4 file, click FILE, EXPORT, and then select output type (default is MP3) and click SAVE. It opens the MP4's audio channel(s), exports the MP3 audio to wherever (and whatever you save it as), and you are out of it (converting a 400-mb MP4 to MP3 on a 3Ghz AMD chip is around 10-minutes, with a 160kb/sec sample rate on the audio, and the audio file will be about half as large as the MP4).