# Sound converter on Ubuntu Gnome offers no option for converting audios to mp3

Tags: gnome, sound, mp3, conversion

I often use sound converter to convert my audio files to mp3 and It works perfectly on Ubuntu Unity but when I move to Ubuntu Gnome there is no option for mp3 format.

Sound converter does show how to install a codec to enable the function but the codec has been already installed on my computer.

How can I enable mp3 coverting, or is there any other software that works?

Answer (score 1):

It might be late, but still for others who are still looking to encode into mp3 using Sound Converter, install `gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly` .

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution in the comments [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/174293/443958).

Reproduced below:

> To enable conversion from mp4 to mp3 in ubuntu 16, I had to do sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras - @wordsforthewise

i.e.,

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

And close and open SoundConverter. :)

P.S

Works on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

The MP3 codec isn't installed by default by Ubuntu but can easily be added by searching for gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 in the software centre or using synaptic...

Comment: gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 is already installed. Still can't convert audio files to mp3.