# How to add MP3 encoder in sound Converter ubuntu 15.10, 14.10 or 14.04

Tags: sound, mp3, mp4, mp3-player, soundconverter

I have installed sound converter from Ubuntu 15.10 repository. But it is not working for MP4 to mp3.

Previous posts are not helping me to sort out this problem !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sound converter on Ubuntu Gnome offers no option for converting audios to mp3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/326023/sound-converter-on-ubuntu-gnome-offers-no-option-for-converting-audios-to-mp3)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly`

Answer (score 0):

You will get it by installing the gstreamer plugin containing the mp3 codec:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
```